# Is $L^\infty(G) \otimes L^\infty(G)$ dense in $L^\infty(G \times G)$?

Tags: tensor-products, topological-groups, von-neumann-algebras

Let $G$ be a Haussdorf locally compact second countable topological group. Denote $\mu$ a Haar mesure on $G$. We can embed the algebraic tensor product $L^\infty(G) \otimes L^\infty(G)$ into $L^\infty (G \times G)$ (with mesure $\mu \otimes \mu$) via $f \otimes g(x,y) = f(x)g(y)$. This embedding is of course injective. My question is weither its image is dense in $L^\infty(G \times G)$ for either norm topology or $\sigma$-weak topology induced by the injection $f \mapsto [m_f : g \mapsto fg]$ of $L^\infty(G \times G)$ into $\mathcal{B}(L^2(G \times G))$.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: It is not dense in the norm topology. Mariano’s comments already present an example. But it is dense in $\sigma$-weak topology.

Comment: How does one prove that is it dense for $\sigma$-weak topology then ? @DavidGao

Comment: I’m not sure what is the easiest way, but I would suggest using the double commutant theorem. You can prove, for example, that $S \otimes S$ is dense in $L^2(G \times G)$, where $S$ consists of simple functions supported on sets of finite measure. Since $S \otimes S \subseteq L^\infty(G) \otimes L^\infty(G)$, this is enough to show that the commutant of $L^\infty(G) \otimes L^\infty(G)$ is contained in $L^\infty(G \times G)$, so the double commutant contains $L^\infty(G \times G)$ (in fact, it would be $L^\infty(G \times G)$). The result then follows from double commutant theorem.